# Executed Query Source

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, datasource

Where is the value of the actual query executed for an AccessDataSource with the parameters replaced with actual values?

**Note:** Answers in VB.NET or C# are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not positive w/r/t AccessDataSource but I don't believe the parameters actually get replaced in the string representing your query.  If they do, it is most likely once the query has already been sent to the database.